# sql notification error running on Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I want to get notification for a new record inserted into the database with this code:

```
var perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
perm.Demand();
SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);

SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
```

// I got an exception here when running the application "Windows 2008 Ent R2 SP1 64Bit"

> Error of starting database Watcher: Cannot find the user 'owner',
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Cannot find the queue
>   'SqlQueryNotificationService-f41563c5-3c26-4469-8447-3ee41c801a55',
>   because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Invalid object name
>   'SqlQueryNotificationService-f41563c5-3c26-4469-8447-3ee41c801a55'.

I already have done this for the database and the user:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET ENABLE_BROKER 
use [dbName] GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [dbUser]
```

So where could be the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx) there are some restriction to the connection you use

Comment: if I run on Windows 7, it runs fine. The only problem is that if I run the program on a Windows 2008 Ent R2 SP1 64Bit!

Comment: it is my fault. I found the problem. I grant wrong permission to another user!